Telegram Mini App authentication not working (angular)
I'm developing a small Telegram Mini App project for University. Building the app using Angular. I'm stuck on authenticating the initData. The poor telegram documentation not helping at all.
Here's my code:
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // validate();
    WebApp.ready();
    // this._validate();
    this.__validate();
  }

  __validate() {
    const data = WebApp.initData
      .split('&') // split by &
      .sort() // sort by key
      .map((item) => {
        const [key, value] = item.split('='); // split by =
        return { [key]: (value) } // return object
      })
      .reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, ...item }), {}); // merge all

    const hash = data['hash']; // save hash

    delete data['hash']; // remove hash

    console.log("data: ", data);

    const data_check_string = Object.keys(data).map(key => `${key}=<${data[key]}>`).join('\n')

    console.log(data_check_string);


    const secretKey = sha256.hmac("WebAppData", this.TOKEN);
    const _hash = sha256.hex(sha256.hmac(secretKey, data_check_string));


    console.log('hash:', hash);
    console.log('_hash:', _hash);



  }

The console ouput on my mini app is:
(I censored some personal info with '...'):

data:  Object
auth_date: "1729515733"
query_id: "..."
user: "{"id"%...%2C"first_name"%3A"Francesco"%2C"last_name"%3A"..."%2C"username"%3A"..."%2C"language_code"%3A"it"%2C"allows_write_to_pm"%3Atrue}"
[[Prototype]]: Object
auth_date=<1729515733>
query_id=<...>
user=<{"id"%...%2C"first_name"%3A"Francesco"%2C"last_name"%3A"..."%2C"username"%3A"..."%2C"language_code"%3A"it"%2C"allows_write_to_pm"%3Atrue}>
hash: 387f5a91d7cbb18405697392b1cac60254c7713f3439acd190a1b1999cf7ff3b
_hash: 84e33c391889ad4b16f918b0a1d87ebe9478992a0d79ab136c095980adeb4b3c

Following this doc
I tried retrieving the data in different ways.
I tried key=value and key=<value> formats
I tried reading different documentations but i can never make it work.
hash and _hash do not match
